# what is gralloc_goldfish?

Tags: android

I recently upgraded my Android SDK to 4.1. While launching apps on my emulator there is a log tagged as "gralloc_goldfish". I did a Google Search, but didn't find any solution. Does any one have any idea on this.

I think it has to do something with 'allocation'. The word goldfish made me curious.

Comment: Goldfish is probably just a codename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goldfish is the name of the linux kernel used for emulator. gralloc is used to allocate memory for graphics

Check [here](http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html) . Quoted from the link

```
The goldfish project contains the kernel sources for the emulated platforms.
```

Answer (score 0):

After some googling I found out that gralloc.goldfish is a part of the emulator that's used if the emulator supports GPU emulation (i.e. simulates a device that has a GPU).

Answer (score -1):

The actual problem with your activity. you should check your Log in that you can find ActivityNotFoundException. then you have to declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: i never said i got an exception :)